# How to create powershell proxy functions module in multiple files?

Tags: c#, powershell, object, module, proxy

In our automation framework, lot of proxy functions are being created.
Normally proxy function will be created by wrapping a function into another function. But our team is creating proxy function by wrapping functions into ScriptMethod. They are doing this to use member variables inside function.

See the below example:

```
function New-StorageArray {
Param
(
    $Name,
    $Credential,
    [version] $Version
)
$array = [pscustomobject] @{
    arrayName = $Name
    arrayCredential = $Credential
    arrayVersion = $version
}

$array | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod ProxyForCmdlet1 {
    Param
    (
        $property1,
        $property2
    )
    try
    {
        Connect-StorageArray -ArrayName $this.ArrayName -Credential $this.ArrayCredential
        $resultOfCmdlet1 = Cmdlet1 -property1 $property1 -property2 $property2
        $status = $true
    }
    catch
    {
        $status = $true
        Write-Error "Some problem occured"
    }
    finally
    {
        Disconnect-StroageArray
    }

    $retObject = [PSCustomObject] @{
        Status = $status
        Result = $resultOfCmdlet1
    }

    return $retObject  

}

$array | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod ProxyForCmdlet2 {   
    # same as ProxyForCmdlet1 except it is wrapper for another cmdlet
}

 $array | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod ProxyForCmdlet3 {   
    # same as ProxyForCmdlet1 except it is wrapper for another cmdlet
} 
return $array     }
```

To Instantiate array of particular version, they follow like below.

```
$arrayVerion5 = New-StorageArray -Name "MAchineIP" -Credential "Credential" -Version "5.0"

   $arrayVersion5.ProxyForCmdlet1("Parameters")

$arrayVerion4 = New-StorageArray -Name "MAchineIP" -Credential "Credential" -Version "4.0"
```

It works good. But when proxy functions are wrapped inside Scriptmethod ,we lose pipelining, Help documentation. When the number of proxy function increases ,we are unable to write it into different files, because it is one function which has all the member function.

In C# they will write partial class and functions can be written across multiple files. But powershell don't have any thing like that.

We are losing powershell advantage of pipeline ,help documentation and also unable to handle complexity when proxy function increases. What is the best alternative approach to this?

Comment: Its tough to deal with. But why do you want to have the proxy functions inside the main function? Why not outside and calling them? That way you can still retain the pipelining..correct me if I am going into the wrong discussion..